# Заменить строку в файле и сохранить его

Tags: php, строки, replace

Есть файл 1.txt:

```
name1|name2|yes
name3|name4|yes
name4|name5|yes
```

В переменную $glob я занес "name4". Я прохожу в цикле по строкам файла. Нахожу строку, в которой есть вхождение строки "name4". Как поменять атрибут "yes" на "no" и сохранить его?

```
 $file = fopen('1.txt', 'r+');
        if($file)
        {
            while(!feof($file))
            {
                $i = fgets($file, 1024);
                $i = explode("|",$i);
                if ( strcmp ( $glob, $i[0]) == 0  ){
                   $string = str_replace("yes","no",$i[0]);
                // 
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
```

Вот что я хочу получить на выходе:

```
   name1|name2|yes
   name3|name4|no
   name4|name5|yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно всё сделать одной регуляркой.

```
$glob = 'name4';
$str = 'name5|name4|yes';
$res = preg_replace('/(?<='.$glob.'\|)yes/', 'no', $str);
// строка изменилась - name5|name4|no
$str = 'name4|name5|yes';
$res = preg_replace('/(?<='.$glob.'\|)yes/', 'no', $str);
// строка без изменения - name4|name5|yes
```

Comment: а как через fwrite переписать эту строку?

Comment: Можно сделать так:

    $glob = 'name4'; // что ищем
    $file = '1.txt'; // файл, с которым работаем
    $data = file($file); // считываем данные файла в массив
    $newData = ''; // измененные данные
    foreach($data as $line){
     $newData .= preg_replace('/(?<='.$glob.'\|)yes/', 'no', $line);// изменяем каждую строку
    }
    file_put_contents($file,$newData); // записываем в файл измененные данные

P.S. Не нужно нажимать "наградить" без лишней на то надобности. Достаточно нажать "Палец вверх"

Comment: регулярка неправильная

Comment: @herberus, регулярка - правильная ([проверяем тут][1]) в рамках тех условий, которые вы указали. Если есть какие-то особенности, то не помешает их указать.

   [1]: http://ideone.com/peQSpc

Comment: В его примере yes на no меняется только если name4 встречается во второй колонке